# GraphQL resolver oddly returns some fields as null

Tags: javascript, typescript, graphql, apollo

In a brief overview, I'm trying to resolve a list of Users. I have an Apollo Server that stitches an accounts-js schema with my own. So I extended the User type to include some additional fields. Though, in this case I was to be able to return only **SOME** fields, the rest null.

```js
getUsers: async (_, __, ctx) => {
    let action = await usersModel.find();
    console.log(action)
    return action;  
},
```

My `me` query does return all of the data without returning a single null field.

```
  extend input CreateUserInput {
    isAdmin: Boolean!
  }

  extend type User {
    isAdmin: Boolean
    profile: Profile
    keys: [Key]
  }

  type Profile {
    avatar: String
    bio: String
  }

  type Key {
    id: ID
    livenet: Boolean
    nickname: String
  }
    
  type Query {
    getUsers: [User]
    me: User
  }
```

Though, when I `console.log(action)` in the resolver for my query `getUsers` these are the documents that gets returned in my console.

```
[ { profile: { bio: 'haha' },
    _id: 5f0a901bdcf725204446c949,
    isAdmin: true,
    services: { password: [Object], email: [Object] },
    createdAt: 1594527771625,
    updatedAt: 1594691054105,
    username: 'ayooo',
    emails: [ [Object] ],
    keys: [ [Object], [Object] ] },
  { profile: { bio: 'testing' },
    _id: 5f0a9439abfce521aba79b2c,
    isAdmin: false,
    services: { password: [Object], email: [Object] },
    createdAt: 1594528825858,
    updatedAt: 1594762680766,
    username: 'lol',
    emails: [ [Object] ],
    keys: [ [Object] ] } ]
```

[image: Text]

If I download my overall GraphQL schema this is what it looks like:

```
directive @auth on FIELD_DEFINITION | OBJECT
input AuthenticateParamsInput {
  access_token: String
  access_token_secret: String
  provider: String
  password: String
  user: UserInput
  code: String
}

input CreateUserInput {
  isAdmin: Boolean!
  username: String
  email: String
  password: String
}

type CreateUserResult {
  userId: ID
  loginResult: LoginResult
}

type EmailRecord {
  address: String
  verified: Boolean
}

type ImpersonateReturn {
  authorized: Boolean
  tokens: Tokens
  user: User
}

input ImpersonationUserIdentityInput {
  userId: String
  username: String
  email: String
}

type Key {
  id: ID
  livenet: Boolean
  exchange: String
  nickname: String
  apiKey: String
  apiSecret: String
}

type LoginResult {
  sessionId: String
  tokens: Tokens
  user: User
}

type Mutation {
  setBio(bio: String): ID
  setAvatar(avatar: String): ID
  changeUsername(username: String): ID
  setKey(
    livenet: Boolean
    exchange: String
    nickname: String
    apiKey: String
    apiSecret: String
  ): ID
  createUser(user: CreateUserInput!): CreateUserResult
  verifyEmail(token: String!): Boolean
  resetPassword(token: String!, newPassword: String!): LoginResult
  sendVerificationEmail(email: String!): Boolean
  sendResetPasswordEmail(email: String!): Boolean
  addEmail(newEmail: String!): Boolean
  changePassword(oldPassword: String!, newPassword: String!): Boolean
  twoFactorSet(secret: TwoFactorSecretKeyInput!, code: String!): Boolean
  twoFactorUnset(code: String!): Boolean
  impersonate(
    accessToken: String!
    impersonated: ImpersonationUserIdentityInput!
  ): ImpersonateReturn
  refreshTokens(accessToken: String!, refreshToken: String!): LoginResult
  logout: Boolean
  authenticate(
    serviceName: String!
    params: AuthenticateParamsInput!
  ): LoginResult
  verifyAuthentication(
    serviceName: String!
    params: AuthenticateParamsInput!
  ): Boolean
}

type Profile {
  avatar: String
  bio: String
}

type Query {
  getUsers: [User]
  getProfile: Profile
  serverTime: String
  me: User
  twoFactorSecret: TwoFactorSecretKey
  getUser: User
}

type Tokens {
  refreshToken: String
  accessToken: String
}

type TwoFactorSecretKey {
  ascii: String
  base32: String
  hex: String
  qr_code_ascii: String
  qr_code_hex: String
  qr_code_base32: String
  google_auth_qr: String
  otpauth_url: String
}

input TwoFactorSecretKeyInput {
  ascii: String
  base32: String
  hex: String
  qr_code_ascii: String
  qr_code_hex: String
  qr_code_base32: String
  google_auth_qr: String
  otpauth_url: String
}

type User {
  username: String
  isAdmin: Boolean
  profile: Profile
  keys: [Key]
  id: ID!
  emails: [EmailRecord!]
}

input UserInput {
  id: ID
  email: String
  username: String
}
```

Mind you that a query of getUser or me returns all the data requested. Where as getUsers would only return a little, mostly null for the important stuff that I need to query on my frontend. I'm trying to list users in a table for my admin panel. Maybe this isn't the best approach? Someone let me know!

[image]

As opposed to querying `me` or `getUser` which returns User. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after knocking out a lot of other things, I came to realize that It was due to me not fully defining my mongoose schema!

```
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useFindAndModify: false,
  useCreateIndex: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});

var usersSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: String,
  isAdmin: Boolean,
  emails: [{ 
    verified: Boolean, 
    address: String 
  }],
  profile: {
    avatar: String,
    bio: String,
  },
  keys: [{ 
    nickname: String,
    exchange: String,
    livenet: Boolean,
    apiKey: String,
    apiSecret: String,
  }]
});

export const usersModel = mongoose.model('Users', usersSchema, 'users');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
type Query {
    getUsers: [User]
    me: User
  }
```

Your query `getUsers` returns array of `User` type.

```
  extend type User {
    isAdmin: Boolean
    profile: Profile
    keys: [Key]
  }
```

Why `extend` ? Does any earlier `User` definition exists? ... anyway **graphQL server returns only fields defined in return type**. Your `User` type has only `isAdmin`, `profile` and `keys` properties. Only those fields will be returned.

**Solution**: Extend your `User` type definition to get other, existing in DB fields.

Comment: as shown above, isAdmin is listed as a field in the extended type of User and still returns null as I query ```getUsers```. I additionally added username to try that and nothing has changed. All that is returned is id, [Keys], and [Profile]

Comment: Are you using some middleware (on graphql server) to restrict access to fields?

Comment: I've tried it with and without @auth added to the type. I was thinking it's just due to how the result is formatted? Though, It seems right. Confused as to why not all the fields are populating :/

Comment: What do you mean by 'Apollo Server that stitches an accounts-js schema' ? stiching/federation? how connected?

Comment: check docs - type definitions in graphiql/playground - probably some types was not merged the way you want (overwritten, not extended?) - change order of args in `mergeTypeDefs`?